# Undefined Error Laravel When retriving Data From Database

Tags: php, database, laravel

Hi I'm having trouble getting data from database after adding a new function inside my controller. Can anyone explain to me this error and what should I do?

I'm using [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBK8Fg8Yq40&t=5259s) as a reference and want to do something like his end result (see 1:09:28 of video), but I get this error:

[image: Error message]

```js
public function manageCategory() {
  $this->authCheck();
  $all_category = DB::table('category')->get();
  $manage = view('admin.pages.manage_category')->with('data', $all_category);
  return view('admin.pages.manage_category')->with('main_content', $manage);
}
```

```html
<tbody>
  @foreach($data as $vData)
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">{{ $vData->category_id }}</a></td>
    <td class="hidden-phone">{{ $vData->category_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $vData->category_description }} </td>
    <td><span class="label label-important label-mini">{{ $vData->category_published }}</span></td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-trash "></i></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: please add the error in detail

Comment: I add Image On my Error...........Please Check It

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code to this

```
public function manageCategory() { 

   $this->authCheck();
   $all_category = DB::table('category')->get(); 

    return view('admin.pages.manage_category')->with('data',$all_category);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing last line and move return keyword like this:

```
public function manageCategory() {
    $this->authCheck();
    $all_category = DB::table('category')
            ->get();
    return view('admin.pages.manage_category')
                ->with('data',$all_category);
}
```

I do not get why there have 2 views called. Maybe u or video maker did mistake

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach should be like this

```
  @foreach($main_content['data'] as $vData)
```

this is because in your controller you $data contains the category but you have assign data to '$manage'.  And again you assign manage to another variable main_content

```
 ->with('main_content', $manage);
```

Comment: or just change your controller to this return   view('admin.pages.manage_category')->with('data',$all_category);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here but this code will help you to fix your an error.

```
public function manageCategory() {
    $this->authCheck();
    $all_category = DB::table('category')->get();

    view()->share('data',$all_category);
    view()->share('main_content',$manage);

    $manage = view('admin.pages.manage_category');
    return view('admin.pages.manage_category');
}
```

View class Share method will help you to share variable to view. 
Good Luck !!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is suite for you..

```
public function manageCategory() {
    $this->authCheck();
    $data = DB::table('category')
            ->get();
    return view('admin.pages.manage_category')
                    ->with('data', $data);  //Directly pass data to view file
}
```

In your blade file ....

```
    @if(!empty($data)) // add if
       @foreach($data as $vData)

                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#">{{ $vData->category_id }}</a></td>
                    <td class="hidden-phone">{{ $vData->category_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $vData->category_description }} </td>
                    <td><span class="label label-important label-mini">{{ $vData->category_published }}</span></td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-trash "></i></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
  @endif  ////add end if
```